# Can't override theme's default text color (android)

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to have only one list view with different text color instead the theme's default color.I can override text size and style and row background color but the text color remains the theme's default. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>

<style name="rowstyle" parent="@style/rowbackground">
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="rowbackground" >
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/row_background</item>
   <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And this is the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.houstone.MainActivity" >

<ListView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/countries"      
  android:id="@+id/cities"
  style="@style/rowstyle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add adapter code also.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself. The solution is to set `android:theme` in the `ListView` instead of `style`, like the OP did

Comment: For creating instance programatically, you might want to use `ContextThemeWrapper` class like following `val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.YourOwnStyle))`